# Gulp-sass only compiling one of the bourbon-neat mixins

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, bourbon, neat

I'm struggling to get gulp to correctly compile bourbon-neat sass files. Bourbon-neat is installed (locally, as are the rest of the gulp-sass related modules), @import 'neat' is added to my main site scss file and my gulp.js file includes the following lines:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),    
neat = require('bourbon-neat').includePaths;
```

and

```
gulp.task('css', function() {    
.pipe(sass({
           includePaths: neat
    }))
}
```

But for some reason the only Neat mixin that's being compiled is box-sizing.scss. So the @import 'neat' is working but for just one of the 23 mixins. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I correct understand question. Did you install bourbon themselves? Cause I didn't see in `require`. Just install Bourbon with neat and your task will looks like that:

```
...
var autoprefix = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
    connect    = require("gulp-connect"),
    gulp       = require("gulp"),
    bourbon    = require("bourbon").includePaths,
    neat       = require("bourbon-neat").includePaths,
    sass       = require("gulp-sass");

var paths = {
  scss: ["./stylesheets/**/*.scss"]
};

gulp.task("sass", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'nested', //for example
        precision: 10,         //for example
        sourcemaps: true,      //for example
        includePaths: [bourbon, neat]
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefix("last 2 versions"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./stylesheets"))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
...
```

And your neat will be run with Bourbon and work together.

In your main scss include bourbon, them neat ...

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";
@import "something_else";
...
```

Hope it will help you to find the way :)